# How to find (grep) text for files in a perforce changelist?

Tags: perforce

How to grep/find for a particular text in all files within a pending changelist?

My use case:
I have a debug_flag in my code and would want to make sure I do not check-in any code with the debug_flag which will cause a compiler error for all others. (Not for me since I have the debug_flag declared locally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p4 describe changelist# gives you the list of the files in a changelist, but it has some extra information, and the paths are with respect to the depo. Example:

> p4 describe 12334

**output**:

Change 12334 by me on 2014/01/04 00:57:08 *pending*

Some test changelist

Affected files ...

... //depot/path/to/my/files/file1#15 edit

... //depot/path/to/my/files/file2#12 edit

With a few search/replace or a simple perls script, you can change this text output to a list of files with actual path and then run grep on them:

```
xargs grep "debug_flag" < file_list.txt
```

Comment: Another command to get just the path info is `p4 -F %path% fstat -Op -Ro -e 1234 //...` That gets just the local path of all files in change 1234 separate by newlines.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get an error message,
Perforce client error. Invalid option : -F

Comment: @kingkong-jnr Just in case anyone else has the same issue: The -F needs to directly follow the p4 (cannot be after fstat)